# TypeError: array([ 0.]) is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, tornado

I have a python file: analyse.py:

```
def svm_analyze_AHE(file_name):

    # obtain abp file
    testdata = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None)
    #print testdata
    testdata_to_transpose = testdata.iloc[:,1]
    #print testdata_to_transpose
    testdata = np.transpose(testdata_to_transpose)
    testdata = testdata.reshape(1, -1)
    #print testdata

    # extract abp values
    #print testdata.shape
    leng = testdata.shape[1]-1
    #print leng
    #T = testdata.iloc[:,leng]
    T =  np.array(testdata[:,0:leng])
    #print T
    testdata = np.array(T)

    # once model is stored, then retrieve it
    model = joblib.load('svm-model-0.pkl') 

    # make predictions
    predicted = model.predict(testdata)

    return predicted
```

The variable "predicted" returns [0.] which is not JSON serialisable. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 2):

`[0.]` is json serializable:

```
>>> json.dumps([0.])
'[0.0]'
```

Since you tagged the question `tornado` (but didn't mention it in your question), I'm going to guess that you're asking tornado to do the json serialization for you and running into the fact that tornado refuses to send arrays as top-level json objects. This is due to concerns about cross-site security vulnerabilities [documented here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write). The recommended workaround is to wrap the array in a dict instead of sending it at the top level.